# Expression Engine - Is it possible for exp:channel:entries tag to have complex filters?

Tags: expressionengine

Coming from Codeigniter and new to Expression Engine, I am at a loss on how to do complex filters on the exp:channel:entries tag.

I am interested in this filters

```
status
start_on
stop_before
```

How do you do you implement filters for a complex condition like this?

```
(status=X|Y|Z AND start_on=A AND stop_before=B) OR (status=X AND start_on=C AND stop_before=D)
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can only use the `search=` parameter to search on “Text Input”, “Textarea”, and “Drop-down Lists” fields unfortunately. So you'd need to use the query module for this.

If you're just querying on those parameters you should be able to get the entry id's you need from the `exp_channel_titles` table, then use something like the [Stash](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/stash) plugin to feed the `entry_id`'s of the results into a regular channel entries tag. Yes it's nominally one more query that way but as EE abstracts the db schema fairly heavily the alternative is to get lost in a mess of `JOIN`s.

So something like (pseudocode, won't work as is):

Get the entries, statuses are just a string in exp_channel_titles, `entry_date` is the date column you want - which is stored as a unix timestamp, so you'll need to select it with something like `DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME(entry_date))` depending on the format of your filter data.

```
{exp:stash:set name="filtered_ids"}{exp:query sql="SELECT entry_id
              FROM exp_channel_titles 
              WHERE status LIKE ...<your filter here>"
            backspace="1"
              }{entry_id}|{/exp:query}{/exp:stash:set}
```

Later in template:

```
{exp:channel:entries
  entry_id="{exp:stash:get name="filtered_ids"}" 
}
  {!--loop --}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Yes it's a mess compared to what you're probably used to in pure CI, but the trade off is all the stuff you get for free from EE (CP, templating, member management etc).

Stash is awesome by the way - can be used to massively mitigate most EE performance issues/get around parse order issues

Answer (score 0):

You can get a lot of this functionality using the [`search=`](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#search-field-name) parameter in your `{exp:channel:entries...}` loop.

It's not immediately clear to me how you'll get the complexity you seek, so you might end up resorting to the [`query module`](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/query/index.html) though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with dates you might find the [DT plugin](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/dt-plugin) useful.